# How to run bash files in IDE like pycharm on OS "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows10"

Tags: bash, shell, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bash-on-windows

- My OS is `win10 X64`, and I have installed *Bash on Ubuntu on Windows*.
- My IDE is Pycharm2017, and I have installed bash-plugins like `BashSupport`, `Shell Process`.

My test file `helloworld.sh` has codes like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Hello, World!"
```

When I run this script in Pycharm, the result like this:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\bash.exe E:/MyCodes/shell/hello-sh/hello.sh
>   /bin/bash: E:/MyCodes/shell/hello-sh/hello.sh: No such file or directory

[image]

Does it possible to run bash scripts in IDE like Pycharm? And how?

Comment: Is it a problem with your `/` (E:/MyCodes/....) try it with E:\MyCodes\....

Answer (score 0):

When you run under WSL, Windows files are mounted on /mnt.
You need to change E:/ to /mnt/e/